# Show product brand name in minicart, cart and checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

I want to show the name of the product in my minicart, cart and checkout page, but it returns `string(0) ""`. This is only occurs in the minicart, cart and checkout page. The brand names are visible on the catalog page. I have also enabled Store > Attributes > Product > Brand > Storefront > Properties > Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront to Yes.

Here is what I have:

```
<strong class="product-item-brand">
    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($product->getData('brand')); var_dump($block->escapeHtml($product->getData('brand'))); ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductBrand()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</strong>
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Override templates:
minicart : `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

and create a plugin for the function `getItemData()` of the class

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
        <plugin name="minicart-product-attribute" type="<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem
{
    public function aroundGetItemData(
        \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ) {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $result['manufacturer'] = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        return \array_merge(
            $result,
            $data
        );
    }
}
```

Override template: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml` into your module `<vendor>/<module>view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string"><Vendor_Module>/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Override Template `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` into your module `view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

```
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: manufacturer -->
                    <!-- ko text: manufacturer --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>
   
            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                           maxlength="12"/>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Do same for other templates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no other way? Maybe a setting that I need to turn on?

Comment: I don't think so! though you can check, else you can apply this solution and if you found this useful then please accept answer and upvote it.